# Fibonacci Sequence and issues with return?

Tags: python, c++, fibonacci

I am trying to learn c++ having already started programming in python. This is a simple program to calculate the fibonacci numbers between two values a,b. However when i run the code only the number 1 is printed and I can not figure out why. I think it is something to do with using return inside the for loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibo(int b,int a=0){
    int x=0;
    int y=1;
    for(int i=0; i<=b; i++){
        int x0=x;
        int z=x+y;
        x=y;
        y=z;
        if(x>a){
            return x0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << fibo(100)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the python function just for reference

```
def fibo(b,a=0):
    x=0
    y=1
    while x<=b:
        z=x+y
        x0=x
        x=y
        y=z
        if x>a:
            print x0
```

I have also tried the following in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibo(int b,int a=0){
    int x=0;
    int y=1;
    for(int i=0; i<=b; i++){
        int x0=x;
        int z=x+y;
        x=y;
        y=z;
        if(x>a){
            cout << x0 <<endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    fibo(100);
    return 0;
}
```

However this gives fibonacci numbers beyond the value of b

Comment: The Python function prints many values. The C++ function only returns one.

Comment: Why have you replaced print with return? Python code is printing each value. C++ code will return in the first value, and first value will always be 1.

Comment: In your python code, you're using `x` as the loop invariant but in your C++ code, you're using `i`. So this is not the same code as the Python one (obviously).

Comment: ohkk, I checked your python code again. What is your b here? Is it a number of elements to print fibonacci or just a value upto which fibonacci has to be print?

Comment: @Arpit the fibonacci numbers are calculated upto b (so the later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the exact port of your code from Python to C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fibo(int b,int a=0){
    int x=0;
    int y=1;
    int z, x0;
    while( x <= b ) {
        z= x + y;
        x0 = x;
        x = y;
        y = z;
        if(x > a) {
            cout << x0 << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    fibo(100);
    return 0;
}
```

In your Python code, if there's no explicit return, the default return value of the function will be `None`. In C++, that's equivalent to a [`void` function](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~cop3014p/lectures/ch7/index.html).

### Why didn't your for loop work?

The for loop is designed to iterate a number of times. Its syntax is:

```
for (initialization; condition; increase) statement;
```

Like the while-loop, this loop repeats statement while condition is true. But, in addition, the for loop provides specific **OPTIONAL** locations to contain an initialization and an increase expression, executed before the loop begins the first time, and after each iteration, respectively.

1. initialization is executed. Generally, this declares a counter
   variable, and sets it to some initial value. This is executed a
   single time, at the beginning of the loop.
2. condition is checked. If it is true, the loop continues; otherwise,
   the loop ends, and statement is skipped, going directly to step 5.
3. statement is executed. As usual, it can be either a single statement
   or a block enclosed in curly braces { }.
4. increase is executed, and the loop gets back to step 2.
5. the loop ends: execution continues by the next statement after it.

Read more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#for.

So let's break down your loop:

```
int x=0;    // initialize x to 0
int y=1;    // initialize y to 1
for(        
  int i=0;  // initialize i to 0
  i<=b;     // keep looping until i is less than or equal to b (a variable passed in)
  i++       // after every single loop iteration, increment i by 1
) {  
    int x0=x;  // initialize x0 to x
    int z=x+y; // initialize z to (x + y)
    x=y;       // assign the value of y to x
    y=z;       // assign the value of z to y
    if(x>a){   // if x is greater than a, print the value of x0
        cout << x0 <<endl;
    }
}
```

In your Python code, you don't have an `i`, you use `x` as your [loop invariant](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~anderson/cs161/wiki/doku.php?do=export_s5&id=slides:week7#slide0). So that should be the `condition` of your for loop: `x <= b`. The initialization part should be the variables you set before you loop, so: `int x = 0, y = 1, x0, z` should be the `initialization`. The last part is the increment. In your python code, your increment is `x = y`, but in a for loop, that part is executed *after* the iteration is done, so we can't just set `x = y` in the increment part of the for loop since `y = z` is executed *before* the increment part. What we can do is use a bit of algebra: `z = y + x`, so we can get the value of `y` by subtracting `x` from `z`: `z - x`.

This makes the for loop:

```
void fibo2(int b,int a=0){
    for(
        int x = 0, y = 1, x0, z;
        x <= b;
        x = (z-x)
    ) {
        x0 = x;
        z = x+y;
        y = z;
        if(x > a){
            cout << x0 <<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works perfectly, I am still struggling with why the for loop does not give the same result however. Or is the issue with the fact that i had the function as a int type rather than void?

Comment: @Chris2807 no that's not the reason. The reason is your for loop in C++ introduced an `i` which you used to stop the loop from continuing to execute. Let me elaborate a bit more in the answer.

Comment: Sorry i realise now why the for loop will not work, was having a slow few minutes there. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibo(int b,int a=0){
    int x=0;
    int y=1;

    while(x<=b)
    {
        int z=x+y;
        int x0=x;
        x=y;
        y=z;
        if(x>a && x<b)
        {
            cout << x << " ";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    fibo(100);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/225KIY

Answer (score 1):

The usual mathematical (recursive) method to compute the sequence up to some `limit` (this is not necessarily the best/most efficient method!): Link to demo [here](http://ideone.com/zRVDFf)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibo(int x) 
{
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    if (x == 1) return 1;

    return fibo(x-1)+fibo(x-2);
}

int main()
{
int j=1,limit=100;

    do
    {
    cout<< fibo(j) <<'\t';
    ++j;
    } while(fibo(j)<=limit);

    return 0;
}
```